# Backpropagation of a transformer

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, bert, transformer

when a transformer model is trained there is linear layer in the end of decoder which i understand is a fully connected neural network. During training of a transformer model when a loss is obtained it will backpropagate to adjust the weights.

My question is how deep the backpropagation is?

- does it happen only till linear layer weights(fully connected neural net) ?
- OR does it extend to all the decoder layer weight matrices(Q,K,V) and Feed forward layers weights?
- OR does it extend to the even the encoder + decoder weights ?

Please help me with the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backpropagation extends to the full model, through all decoder and encoder layers up to the embedding tables.

Comment: hence specifically i understand as weights backpropagated for 1.final linear layer weights, 2.decoder(Feed forward layer weights & Q, K ,V weight matrices), 3. encoder(Feed forward layer weights & Q, K ,V weight matrices) am i right? or am i missing out any other weights getting updated

Comment: You are missing the embeddings themselves.

Comment: thanks, out of curiosity i ask, does the same happens for bert too, i mean the update of embedding matrix during the pretraining process

Comment: Yes, it is the same for BERT.

Comment: thanks finally is there any reference /links on the mathematical update of these weights in transformer i can refer on !

Comment: I am not aware of any reference for the backpropagation derivations specific to the Transformer blocks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119381/discussion-between-prog-and-noe).